# Custom php.ini when using #!/usr/bin/php

Tags: php

I have a script in which I am trying to load a custom `php.ini` file.  The script is run on *nix systems via a `#!/usr/bin/php -qc /path/to/php.ini` header.  When doing this, however, PHP reports that the loaded `php.ini` file does not exist, i.e. none is loaded.

If I execute `php -qc /path/to/php.ini /path/to/script` in the command line directly, it picks up the `php.ini` -- is it possible to override the `php.ini` file using the `#!` notation?

Comment: Have you tried it without the `q` just to test? According to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#95272), the shebang notation seems to have problems with multiple options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not like parsing arguments from the shebang. It only allows one to be present. You can however trick it by omitting the space for the first argument parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -qc/etc/php5/my.ini
```

(Obviously this method only works for one such parameter with concatenated argument.)

Comment: Probably depends on the version. (Works for my php-cgi and php-cli in 5.3, and I've been using it since 4.2 iirc.)

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work removing the spaces for me either, that was on php 5.3.5, but you're definitely right about it no parsing the arguments, so you got it!

Comment: Works on Arch Linux build of 7.1 as of 2019-05-01

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this shebang portability *specification fail* by wrapping your PHP script in a Shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
SCRIPT_PATH="$(dirname $0)"
/usr/bin/env php -qc /path/to/php.ini -f $SCRIPT_PATH/my_original_script.php
```