# Starting PHP With Incremental Configuration

Tags: php, centos, command-line-interface

Let's say I want to use the default `php.ini` plus several settings I need for just a few .php-files:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

I know of the `-c` parameter, but that seems to expect a full `php.ini`. What I want is to tell PHP to use the default `php.ini` and a small configuration file like above, which overwrites the settings in `php.ini`.

How do I do that?

EDIT:
Sorry about the context thing: it should be shebang-kind of style:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -cphp-with-errors.ini
```

The problem is that I can only add one parameter to PHP, i.e. a bunch of `-d` won't work.

Comment: In what context? CLI usage like `$ php ...`?

Comment: @deceze I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `php` executable accepts the `-d` parameter for this purpose:

```
$ php -d error_reporting=32767 -d display_errors=On file.php
```

In the context of a web server, you can use `php_value` and `php_flag` in an htaccess file. See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php.

Comment: 1) It works for a shebang line as well and 2) you could just set it in PHP code to begin with, if it's in the PHP file anyway.

Comment: 1) doesn't work for my shell, 2) is an option, but I shouldn't mess with the PHP-files.

Comment: 1) Define how it doesn't work? Works for me. Note that `E_ALL` does't work outside of PHP or the INI, you need to use the bit mask values instead. Perhaps that's the only issue?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5332214/483113). Note that the unchecked answer is an option, but requires some more work. If I can get an easier way to solve this I'd appreciate that.

Comment: We decided to delve into the code and follow this approach.